# how to write function sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to write function with one parameter and return two columns. i tried below code

```
create function fun_initial_score (@phy_id varchar(20))
returns  table
as


declare @vc int;

set @vc =(select MAX(visited_count) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level )


 return (SELECT 
    pflag.Score, 
    pflag.Disability_Level

FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
    inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
and pflag.visited_count=@vc)
```

i know above code show error but i need write function with above concept. how to write it.can anyone help me....thanks...

Comment: `@initial__score` is a scalar variable. It can only ever contain a single value. Do you want the function to return a *result set* consisting of two columns?

Comment: i edited my code see it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to write an [inline table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx), then the entire body of the function can only be a single select statement provided to `return`. But thankfully, that seems feasible here. I don't see a reason for the separate query and variable to hold `@vc`:

```
create function fun_initial_score (@phy_id varchar(20))
returns  table
as
 return (SELECT 
    pflag.Score, 
    pflag.Disability_Level

FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
    inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
and pflag.visited_count=(select MAX(visited_count) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level ))
```

Comment: thanks i got it...but i need select from two function i tried this "select * from (dbo.fun_initial_score('01091400003') , dbo.fun_current_score('01091400003'));"

Comment: @user3170098 - you shouldn't need to *call* the function twice, but you should provide an alias for the result set it produces: `select * from dbo.fun_initial_score('01091400003') alias_name`